# Visual Studio 2010 hangs after renaming projects in large solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, freeze, renaming

I have 1 large solution (about 100 c# projects and 20 c++ projects) in VS2010 + Resharper.

Well known steps for c# project renaming :

1. Rename project via project explorer.
2. Open project properties (right click) -> rename "Assembly name" and "Default namespace"
3. Open Assembly Info file -> rename neseccary properties in this file
4. Remove renamed projects from solution
5. Rename projects directiories on file system
6. Load renamed projects

After performing these steps for some C# projects (for example I renamed 10 projects), Visual Studio 2010 hangs. Work with the solution becomes fully impossible. It occurs on any machine when I try to open this solution.

The goal is to rename all projects. For example, every project's name pattern is : XXX.YYY.ZZZ and I want to rename them all according to a new pattern : YYY.ZZZ.

Answer (score 0):

With more than 100 projects in two different languages it is very normal for VS2010 to freeze.I have about only 45 projects , Changing a class name freezes VS for a noticeable amount of time.
Then even though tedious i switched to Find and Replace,Basic but doesn't freeze VS..There is no other go. You have to deal with it.
Btw VS also needs a Huge database for maintaining c++ references and parsing information.